# Скачать файл с чужого dropbox по публичной ссылке на сервер

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dropbox

Возникла необходимость скачать файл с чужого Dropbox по публичной ссылке без всякого рода авторизации и аутентификации. Требуется сохранить этот файл на сервере с node.js в конкретную папку. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ сделать это? Например, имеется такая ссылка на файл: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/dr1cit55idwi1m0/english_buisness_message.txt?dl=0`

Answer (score 0):

В общих чертах:

```
var https = require('https'), 
    fs = require('fs'); 
var fStreamOut = fs.createWriteStream('/any/path/to/output-file.txt');
https.get('https://anyURL/', response => response.pipe(fStreamOut))
  .on('error', err => { /* обработка ошибок */ });
```

Comment: В таком варианте я пробовал, но по итогу получаю пустой файл.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov, проблемы при скачивании - это *совершенно другой вопрос*. Соответственно, оформите отдельным вопросом, с указанием вашего кода и детальным описанием проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

В конкретно моем случае сработало следующее:
вначале я заменил в конце ссылки '0' на '1'

```
    var link = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/dr1cit55idwi1m0/english_buisness_message.txt?dl=0"
    var firstPart = link.split("=")[0];
    link = firstPart + '=1';
    var myFile = request(link).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./dist/testtest.txt'));
      myFile.write(resFull.data);
      myFile.end(() => {
        /..here is callback function../
     })
```